# Making a module show on articles without a menu item beeing associated to them in joomla

Tags: joomla

I have a multilingual site, with some articles that do not have a menu item linking to them. They are connected to the rest of the site through links on other articles.

The problem I have is that I cannot select the articles without menu item to display the module. The solution suggested [here](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_control_module_display_when_linking_to_an_article_with_no_menu_item) seems somewhat complicated to do every time if you have lots of articles.

Since it is a bilingual site and I want the module to only show on the German or English pages, I though it might be possible to display one of the modules on all English pages and the other on all German pages?!

Another possibility would be to display it on all articles that are within a certain category, as I have a category for each language. Any suggestions as to how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Assign Module to all pages and set some module position according to language's like

```
custom_position_eng this stands for a module position for English
```

and on the corresponding article pages you can load the module with calling like below.

```
{loadposition custom_position_eng}
```

This method will help you to show modules in article pages with out a menu related with it.Also it help to display different module on different languages etc.

If you have more article and position not work practically and you are also unable to assign to that module to a menu then try this,

You can load any module anywhere with following methods.

```
 $document = &JFactory::getDocument();
 $renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module');

 $Module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_fmDataGrid');

 $Params = "param1=bruno\n\rparam2=chris";//This will only required when you pass module params through code
 $Module->params = $Params;
 echo $renderer->render($Module);
```

So if you are using article layout with override concept try to edit the template and add the code with proper module names. else you have to edit Joomla core files with this (Its a bad idea editing core files not recommended).

Hope its helps..

Comment: thanks for your answer, however, it still seems to be rather complicated and a lot of effort needs to go into it if we are speaking about hundreds of articles.
From what I have understood I need to load the module within every article?! If so, that is why I thinks it would take up a lot of time, besides, I would need to adapt all of my css and div positioning for two possible scenarios, (one loading the module the normal way and the other loading it through the article?!
Is there not a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: Where do I need to copy the code to? Into the index.php included in my template? I should probably say that I am using a custom template...

Comment: If you are using custom template check following path templates/your_template/html/com_content/artciles/ then edit the layout files which one is loading articles, No need to edit on index page only article layout need to add the codes.

Comment: I made an override of com_content already, the only files that I have in the article folder though are default.php, default.xml and default_links.php. I suppose that by layout files you mean the default.php?!? If so, where in that file should I post the above code?

Comment: where you need to display the module on the default.php place there.

Comment: It turned out that it works without the above code, I followed all the steps through but skipped the code bit. The reason was that when I added the code too, it ended up on the front end.

Answer (score 2):

This is easily accomplished by using the free extension "advanced module manager": https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager

It allows you set set the assignment for that module using dozens of parameters including specific articles.